# How to increment a conditional statement based on the five times table?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve the following within my conditional statement:

```
if (changeCount == 5 || changeCount == 10 || changeCount == 15 || changeCount == 20) {
  Do Something
}
```

I want to let the conditional statement pass if the value of the `changeCount` is any number in the five times table.

At the moment I have used the `||` however this is no good because I need it to be infinite.

I feel like a noob asking this question but any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Also FYI: `changeCount == 5 || 10 || 15 || 20` is not as same as `changeCount == 5 || changeCount ==10 || changeCount ==15 || changeCount ==20` So your implementation was anyway wrong!

Comment: It's not clear what you expect. and this condition with `||` doesn't work like you expect - it will always be true.

Comment: Sorry guys I have amended this, my mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator (also known as the *mod* operator)

```
if (changeCount % 5 === 0) {
  // do something
}
```

It works by dividing *arg1* by *arg2*, and returning the remainder. If the remainder is 0, then it divides evenly.

If you wanted to limit the range of `changeCount` and still ensure that it is divisible by 5, you could do something like this:

```
if (changeCount >= lowerBound 
    && changeCount <= upperBound 
    && changeCount % 5 === 0) {
```

Comment: What if the changeCount is 25?

Comment: @stavros.zavrakas "**I need it to be infinite**" - Check question.

Comment: @sabithpocker "I need it to be infinite". Infinite does not mean that it should be translated as 'something mod 5'. Is this the definition of infinite? I just read the code and not the whole explanation.

Comment: `25` is probably fine, but how about `0` ?

Comment: @stavros.zavrakas I guess his answer would be termed correct as the questioner wanted the counts from table of 5.

Comment: @georg That's right, probably OP need to update this.